# how to determine the truth value of a statement?

Tags: logic

How do I know if this statement is true or false?

How do you read something like that:

$$\forall x\exists y\mid x^{2} = y$$

Comment: For every $x$ there exists $y$ such that $x^2=y$

Answer (score 5):

There should be domains for $x$ and $y$.If it was $\forall x \in \mathbb{N},\exists y \in \mathbb{N}: x^2 = y $, it would be true and will read "for all x in $\mathbb{N}$", there exists $y$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2 = y $.

Comment: You are right. But here, I'm saying that there exists $y$ s.t. it is the square of the natural number.

Answer (score 2):

It is false if
$$
\lnot (\forall x \exists y  \mid x^2 = y) 
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
 \exists x \forall y \mid x^2 \neq y
$$
is true. To prove this statement, you must find some $x$ such that $x^2 \neq y$ for any $y$.

A proof that the statement is true might look something like this: Fix an arbitrary $x$. Find a $y$ (which could depend on $x$) susch that $x^2 = y$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we may conclude that the statement is true.